# Pagination not working using Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I have a problem with firebase pagination.

I have table posts and this is an example structure:

[image]

and I want to get only 10 post every time, here is my code page is 0:

```
 @NonNull
    @CheckResult
    public Single<DataSnapshot> getData(@NonNull DatabaseReference ref, int page) {
        return Single.create(emitter -> {

            ref.orderByChild("timestamp")
                    .startAt(page * 10)
                    .limitToFirst(10);


            final ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                        emitter.onSuccess(dataSnapshot);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                        emitter.onError(databaseError.toException());
                    }
                }
            };

            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
        });
    }
```

and here is the result

[image]
Why I have list size equals 20 not 10? p.s. limit to first or limit to last it's no difference with the result

Comment: may be coz there are two users. Also, you are limiting the number of users to be 10 not the number of post per user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `startAt()`, `limitToFirst()` and similar methods on a `DatabaseReference` returns a new `Query` object. You need to keep a reference to that `Query` and attach your listeners to that:

```
Query query = ref.orderByChild("timestamp")
                 .startAt(page * 10)
                 .limitToFirst(10);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```